# add column to pivot table

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

there.
I want to add a column to pivot table since creating pivot table and adding column are within one request.
And here is the code:
private void generatePreview(XSSFWorkbook wb) {
XSSFSheet inputSheet = wb.getSheet("Input"); // this the data source of pivot table
XSSFSheet previewSheet = wb.createSheet("Preview"); // this is the pivot table
XSSFPivotTable xssfPivotTable = previewSheet.createPivotTable(areaR, pos, inputSheet);
...
}
columns:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QherI.png)
Qty and Unit Price are from "Input", how can I add "Extended Price"?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtN6m.png)
those three fields are Values.

```
private void addCalculatedField(XSSFPivotTable xssfPivotTable, CTPivotFields pivotFields, CTPivotTableDefinition pivotTableDefinition) {
    CTCacheFields cacheFields = xssfPivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields();
    CTCacheField cacheField = cacheFields.addNewCacheField();
    cacheField.setName("Extended Price");
    cacheField.setFormula("'Group Qty' * 'Group Price'");
    cacheField.setNumFmtId(0);

    CTPivotField pivotField = pivotFields.addNewPivotField();
    pivotField.setDataField(true);
    pivotField.setShowAll(false);

    CTDataFields dataFields;
    if(pivotTableDefinition.getDataFields() != null) {
        dataFields = pivotTableDefinition.getDataFields();
    } else {
        dataFields = pivotTableDefinition.addNewDataFields();
    }
    CTDataField dataField = dataFields.addNewDataField();
    dataField.setName("Group Total Price");
    dataField.setFld(cacheFields.getCount());
    DataFormat dataFormat = xssfPivotTable.getParentSheet().getWorkbook().createDataFormat();
    short format = dataFormat.getFormat("$#,##0.00_)");
    dataField.setNumFmtId(format);
}
```

Though the "Extended Price" is added, but it is not ticked and does not show on the table.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vvjq.png)